# Commands for discord bot not working (Python)

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am not sure why the commands don't work. Whenever I enter !hello into my discord server the bot doesnt respond.

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import os

my_secret = os.environ['Token']
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')

@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def hello(ctx):
  await ctx.send("Hello")


client.run(my_secret)
```

Answer (score 0):

This should Work
I just tested it and it worked fine
did you install Discord? and did you wrote your Token right?

Also you should put this Code in yours so you see when the Bot is ready

```
@client.event
async def on_ready():
print(" ")
print("Bot started! | Informations:")
print(f"- Name: {client.user.name}") 
print(f"- Bot-ID: {client.user.id}") 
print(f"- Server using {client.user.name}:",
      len(client.guilds))
```

Comment: Yes I have my token and everything that turns on my bot and stuff. I am trying to add commands to my bot and my bot doesnt send anything in the chat when I type the trigger word.

Comment: Does your Bot have Permissions to view the messages from the chat?